# Asp.net 5 website fails to resolve the dependencies in IIS on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to run an MVC 6 website under IIS on a Windows 2008 r2 machine but getting the following error. The same website work fine without IIS using `web.cmd`.

```
Failed to resolve the following dependencies for target framework 'Asp.Net,Version=v5.0':
  BouncyCastle 1.7.0.0
  EntityFramework 7.0.0-beta3-12021
  EntityFramework.Commands 7.0.0-beta3
  EntityFramework.Migrations 7.0.0-beta2-11941
  EntityFramework.Relational 7.0.0-beta3-12021
  EntityFramework.SqlServer 7.0.0-beta3
  ....and a whole long list....
```

Below is my web.config. I am already pointing IIS to `wwwroot` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="kpm-package-path" value="..\approot\packages" />
    <add key="bootstrapper-version" value="1.0.0-beta3" />
    <add key="runtime-path" value="..\approot\packages" />
    <add key="kre-version" value="1.0.0-beta3" />
    <add key="kre-clr" value="clr" />
    <add key="kre-app-base" value="..\approot\src\MySite" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Here is my project.json

```
{
"webroot": "wwwroot",
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"dependencies": {

    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta3",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta3",

    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta3",
    /* "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "6.0.0-beta3", */
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta1",

    "EntityFramework": "7.0.0-beta3-12021",
    "EntityFramework.Relational": "7.0.0-beta3-12021",
    "EntityFramework.Migrations": "7.0.0-beta2-11941",

    "Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities": "1.0.0-beta3-10816",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.FileSystems": "1.0.0-beta3-10698",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0.0-beta-22416",
    "System.Data.Common": "1.0.0-beta2",

    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity": "3.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Google": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.Framework.OptionsModel": "1.0.0-beta3",

    "HtmlAgilityPack": "1.4.9.0",
    "YUICompressor.NET": "2.7.0.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.7.0",
    "Moq": "4.2.1409.1722",
    "System.Linq.Dynamic": "1.0.4.0",
    "System.Net.Primitives": "4.0.10.0-beta-22416",

    "Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-beta3-10674",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Cache.Redis": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Cache.Memory": "1.0.0-beta3"

},
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
    "gen": "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
},
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {
        "frameworkAssemblies": {
            "System.Web.Services": ""
        }
    },
    /*"aspnetcore50": {}*/
},
"exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
],
"bundleExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.kproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
],
"scripts": {
    "postrestore": [ "npm install" ],
    "prepare": [ "grunt bower:install" ]
}
}
```

**UPDATE:** 
I have tried to run a basic sample app on Windows 10 and it did not work for me. Here is the link: http://www.filedropper.com/iissampleapp

I think the problem is that I am trying to have two web apps in the solution?

Comment: Could you please paste the project.json? It seems you combined beta2 and beta3 version of EntityFramework, that might result in problems.

Comment: How did you deploy to IIS? Did you bundle the app first using `kpm bundle`?

Comment: I didn't use kpm bundle. I just published it on File system using Visual Studio and then FTP to server.

Comment: I have got two web applications in my project. Could that be an issue? The main web app is dependent on the other one.

Comment: Any specific reason that you refer to EntityFramework beta3 but EntityFramework.Migrations beta2? you'd better refer to the same version since they are all parts of EntityFramework and may refer to each other. Referring to different versions of the same package might lead to the problem you met.

Comment: I think It's because I am unable to find beta3 in package manager for EntityFramework.Migrations.

Comment: Here is a basic sample project http://www.filedropper.com/iissampleapp . I think the problem is that I need to have two web apps in the solution.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it does not work in windows 10 as well.

Comment: Have you enabled ASP.Net in IIS?  Windows Features -> Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Application Development Features -> Asp.Net 3.5/4.5

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using both `beta2` and `beta3` packages. Do not mix them, that's just looking for trouble. In your case you have `EntityFramework.Relational 7.0.0-beta3-12021` and `EntityFramework.Migrations 7.0.0-beta2-11941`. Also, do not mix dev and release packages. Dev packages are the ones that have a 4-5 digit number at the end (like `12021`) and release packages are those that simply end with `beta3` or `beta2`. They were produced at different moments in time and it is not guaranteed they will work together.
2. After you fix the packages, try this:

   In your app's folder run (replace x64 with x86 if you target a 32 bit machine):

   ```
   kpm bundle --runtime kre-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta3
   ```

   That will produce a folder that contains your application, its dependencies and the CLR.

   Then copy under the website root in IIS and try to run again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer victor. Did u try to run the sample app i attached in comments. This app does not mix any beta2 and 3.  It's the most basic app but still not working.